# How to get special fonts for keywords in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, colors, fonts, keyword

I was watching a C++ video by The Cherno, and noticed that he gets italics/different fonts depending on the keywords he types. Here is an image:
[image]

Does anyone know what font he's using and how he configured "main" and "string" to be italicized? Thanks!

Comment: `Visual Studio`  or `Visual Studio Code`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Visual Studio

Comment: I think the font is **Consolas**, a very nice monospaced font suitable for programming by the incredible Luc de Groot.

Comment: If the reply below is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the look of the code, I am pretty sure that the screenshot shows the syntax highlighting set by [Visual Assist in dark mode](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W179) by default. The italic font for system symbols is [one specific feature](http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W181) of that plugin.

Maybe you can also get the same effect using the [Reshaper C++ plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance_in_CPP.html#syntaxHighlighting), but I personally have not used it before, so I cannot confirm this.

Unfortunately, both plugins are commercial. I am not aware of a free plugin that allows such a kind of context sensitive choice of fonts.

The font itself is most likely Consolas, which is (AFAIK) the default in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `italic` option in Visual Studio `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Font and Colors` settings.

I suspect that there is some plugin involved. Obviously you can do it - see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarRwemi.BetterComments

Comment: Thanks for helping, although not exactly what I'm looking for, I'll try out that extension.

Comment: @ThiccTheo Oh, I didn't mean that it will allow you to italicize keywords, just to point that it is possible.